# Как отдать в браузере пользовательский QML интерфейс?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

Есть приложение написанное на Qt5.11 с использованием QML в качестве GUI, вопрос в том как можно реализовать использование этого интерфейса в браузере, забиваем в адресной строке IP и порт сервера, выходим на GUI приложения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен webgl streaming, он позволяет отдать в браузер ui, написанный на qml, только как раз в 5.11 он сломан. Плюс требует пересборки Qt с флагом `--opengl es2` если я не ошибаюсь.

Немного больше информации
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/qt-webgl-streaming-merged/

https://evileg.com/ru/post/292/

Comment: Собрал с плагином но выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите что с этим делать /* This plugin does not support dynamic OpenGL loading!

ERROR: No native SystemTrayIcon implementation available.
Qt Labs Platform requires Qt Widgets on this setup.
Add 'QT += widgets' to .pro and create QApplication in main().


ERROR: No native Menu implementation available.
Qt Labs Platform requires Qt Widgets on this setup.
Add 'QT += widgets' to .pro and create QApplication in main(). /* мой интерфейс теперь следует переписать ?

Comment: ну так иконки трея в браузере и не может быть, для такой сборки ее надо убирать